# Calendar picker indicator should be default

Tags: html, css

When I hover the mouse over it I get an indicator but I need to set as default

```
 <input type="date" class="form-control" name="Date" 
     [(ngModel)]="opening_date" (ngModelChange)="Operating()"
        style="width:550px" required>

input[type="date"]:default::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: block;
}
```

[image]

please help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply the `opacity:1` instead of `display: block` property.

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator{
  opacity:1;
}
```

If you want to customize the other properties in the date field or other html5 fields then go through [this](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/04/15/list-of-pseudo-elements-to-style-form-controls/#input_date) link. It has all the information.

```css
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="Date" style="width:550px" required>
```